# AWS Sagemaker inference looping

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fastapi, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a custom docker container for the purpose of YOLOV8 inference. The requirements for inference despite the container is a model.tar uploaded to s3, which I also have. While the inference works as expected, the route /invocations is looping, providing consecutive inferences which are not invoked by me, making the EC2 instance burn money. I am invoking the endpoint via an API call within a FastApi POST route.

I have tried to call an Exception after every inference in my container, which yielded the same. I looked into the request timeout when invoking the Sagemaker endpoint, lowered it to 10 seconds and disabled retries, and it remains the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share your predictor.py? Is there a loop within the /invocations path you have defined, the endpoint is simply executing what's within your /invocations path you have defined. SageMaker Docker Containers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html